# Extract Dates From String (textbox)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to loop through and find all dates within a textbox, regardless of format. I think I have my regex working. However, when trying to populate a combo box I am having difficulty.

Maybe my code is a bit messy and I am doing it the wrong way. Wha What I mean by that is it's putting every word in the combo box instead of just dates.

However, here is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Call dates1

End Sub


Function ExtractDates(S As String)
  With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
      .Pattern = .Pattern = "^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$"
      .Global = True
      ExtractDates = Replace(Trim(.Replace(S, " $1")), " ", ", ")
  End With
End Function  


Sub dates1()

Dim dates1 As String
Dim dates2 As String

dates2 = ExtractDates(Me.txtS.Text)

Dim optarray
Dim opt

optarray = Split(dates2, ",")

With Me.ComboBox1
  .Clear
  For opt = 0 To UBound(optarray)
    .AddItem (optarray(opt))
  Next opt
End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What does "having difficulty" mean? Can you close down the spaces in your code please to make it more readable?

Comment: Ammended it without spaces

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this if anyone else is interested:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
CountDates (Me.TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Function CountDates(S As String) As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim result As String
Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

Const sPat As String = "\b(?:\d{1,2}/){2}(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b"

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

With RE
    .Pattern = sPat
    .Global = True
    Set MC = .Execute(S)
    CountDates = MC.Count
    
    CountDates = CountDates - 1
      
    If MC.Count <> 0 Then
        For i = 0 To CountDates
          Me.ComboBox1.AddItem (MC.Item(i))
        Next i
    End If
End With

End Function
```